# What are the proper names to the parts of the conditional probability

Tags: probability, article-writing

I'm writing a paper in which I need to refer to the two parts of a conditional probability $P(A|B)$. Just to be clear, in the context of my paper, I cannot simply write "$A$ conditioned on / given $B$". This is because the probability function is actually defined over multiple random variables and the partition to $A$ and $B$ is not constant but depend on other factors, such as special properties for a variable to belong to either $A$ or $B$.

After searching for a while I couldn't find any consistent answers on the matter, where the closest I've encounter were references to $B$ as the "conditional part". At the moment, I'm using as placeholders "conditional" and "consequent" parts (also considered "antecedent" instead of "conditional"), but I could barely find other references using the latter. Someone has suggested to me to use the "left-side" and "right-side", but it can conflict with the description of equations.

If there are any proper names to these parts, or at least better names than the above, then I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I have seen the term "conditioning event" for $B$ several times.

Comment: just an opinion, really - but personally I would find "antecedent" and "consequent" confusing, unless you state very clearly that this is what you mean by them

Comment: I totally agree, these names are not really good options -- I've only used them as placeholders for my drafts. Following @SangchulLee advise, I think "conditioning variable / event" is a good option for that part, but I still need something for the "consequent" part.

Comment: Two years after, I wanted to give a short update on how I handled this in my paper (now published) in the hope that it might be helpful to others. I ended up using "effective" and "conditioning" variables. In the context of my article it made sense. I'm studying a computational graph of simpler functions that under some structural constraints represent normalized distributions. "effective" made sense because for the most part these constraints are defined w.r.t. these "effective" variables. So, my general "tip" is to take a step back and think on the context instead of the "pure" definition.